# Как в документе Word снять режим ограниченной функциональности, чтобы он был доступен для внесения изменений?

Tags: c#, com, ms-word, office, interop

В общем делаю отчет с заменой определённых слов на конкретные значения… Нужно, чтобы изменения в файле оставались… Но у меня почему то работает режим ограниченной функциональности… В каких методах, в каких параметрах это ставится? Работа в форматах `.doc` и `.docx`

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Создаём новый Word.Application
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        //Загружаем документ
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = null;

        object fileName = "E:\\R.doc";
        object falseValue = false;
        object trueValue = true;
        object missing = Type.Missing;

        doc = app.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing, ref trueValue,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

        //Теперь у нас есть документ который мы будем менять.

        //Очищаем параметры поиска
        app.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting();
        app.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting();

        //Задаём параметры замены и выполняем замену варианта применеия.
        object findText = "<VARIANT>";
        object replaceWith = "на что меняем";
        object replace = 2;

        app.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref replaceWith,
        ref replace, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        app.Visible = true;
app.DisplayAlerts = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
        doc.Saved = true;
        //doc.Close(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions.wdSaveChanges);
        //app.Quit(false);

    }
```

Comment: Можно вопрос? А зачем вы пишете такую портянку с кучей `ref`? Ведь для открытия к примеру, можно просто использовать `app.Documents.Open("Путь");`, это ведь в сотни раз красивее и удобней!

Comment: Дело в том, что я пока только  разбираюсь с языком C# вообще

Comment: теперь буду знать

Answer (score 1):

Файлы формата RTF всегда открываются в режиме ограниченной функциональности.

Используйте родные форматы .doc или .docx в зависимости от версии.

Comment: Хорошо... Тогда аналогичный вопрос с форматами .doc и .docx.... У меня с ними такая же проблема.... Если быть точнее, я с них начинал..