# Почему Word открывается в режиме только для чтения

Tags: c#, com, ms-word, office-interop

Не могу понять в чем дело. Вроде бы скопировал у себя же рабочий код, но почему-то не работает. А не работает потому что word открывается в режиме для чтения.
Хотя перед этим всё работало.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        //показываем панель для введения значений в бланк 
        panel2.Visible = true;
        //скрываем изображение 
        pictureBox1.Visible = false;

        //Создаём новый Word.Application
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        //Загружаем документ
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = null;


        //вариант открытия существующего файла
        object fileName = "E:\\R1.rtf";
        object falseValue = false;
        object trueValue = false;
        object missing = Type.Missing;

        doc = app.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing, ref trueValue,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

        //Теперь у нас есть документ который мы будем менять.

        //Очищаем параметры поиска
        app.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting();
        app.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting();

        //Задаём параметры замены и выполняем замену нп поле варианта 
        object findText = "<VARIANT>";
        object replaceWith = VarApply;
        object replace = 2;

        app.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref replaceWith,
        ref replace, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        app.Visible = false;

        doc.Save();
        doc.Close(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions.wdSaveChanges);
        app.Quit(false);
        richTextBox1.LoadFile("E:\\R1.rtf");

    }
```

Не хочет сохранять изменённый файл в строке `doc.Save()`;

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/730156/220553

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 doc = app.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing, ref trueValue,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

Третий параметр - ReadOnly, поставьте его missing.

Да и вообще можно написать кратко

```
app.Documents.Open(ref fileName)
```

Comment: У меня тогда вопрос... Почему у меня этот код работал раньше?

Comment: Это мог быть не совсем этот код. Я смотрю на тот, который в вопросе.

Comment: Я понимаю... но.. я пользвался им до этого... и всё работало.. а сейчас нет... и Лично я его собрал по крупицам из инета, и тут на тебе он не работает

Comment: Код надо понимать. Параметр заставляет открывать readonly.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.open.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Так он же стоит здесь  False

Comment: Зачем??????????

Comment: Убедитесь, что файл не имеет атрибут read-only. Убедитесь,  что файл не открыт в ворде. Не пишите     object trueValue = false; это все равно, что назвать черное белым.

Comment: Так в итоге то получается, что атрибут отключён... А на счет файла убеждён, потому что просто missing помогло